# <security> tag requirement in consuming WCF with SAML token and using Federation binding

Tags: wcf, wif, saml-2.0, ws-security, wsfederationhttpbinding

we have STS service whihc provides SAML token within the organization for security reasons all apps should get this token. I am buiulding a WCF service which should accept a SAML token and validate the same before serving the request.

So far I have setup a Federationbinding [not sure though its intended requirement as my service serves only interal/intranet apps within the firewall. I managed to to hit my WCF by using SOAP UI and get the response as well while debugging. but, the strange thing is in the request I had to mask my SAML under security tag else it never works; I am wondering ius there any workaroun for this or this is intended use. as the Java clients will be consuming my WCF service.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.30319.17929, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EncryptionCertificateName" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="AssertionSignatureCertificateName" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="EnablePerformanceLog" value="false" />
    <add key="Logging.Level" value="0" />
    <add key="Logging.Active" value="True" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.4000" newVersion="3.3.1.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" optimizeCompilations="true" batch="true" maxConcurrentCompilations="8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" minFreeThreads="10" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="10" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False" bypassonlocal="True" autoDetect="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="5000" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All">
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="Service.svc" service="XX.XXX.BusinessService.Service.VaultService" factory="XX.XXXX.BusinessService.Service.WcfServiceFactory" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <bindings>
      <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ws2007Binding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="BearerKey" issuedTokenType="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="XX.XXXX.BusinessService.Service.Service">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost/XX.XXX.BusinessService.Service/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws2007Binding" contract="XX.XXXX.Contract.Service.ServiceContract.IService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.4000" newVersion="3.3.1.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
      <!--<audienceUris>
        <add value="VaultService.svc"/>
      </audienceUris>-->
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add name="XX-XX-XX" thumbprint="XXX" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add type="XX.XXX.Extension.Security.MySecurityTokenHandler, XXX.XXX.Extension" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="XX.XXXX.Extension.Security.ClaimsAuthenticationManager, XX.XXXX.Extension" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <location path="health-check.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

      <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

the sample request that works from SOAP UI:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soa="http://XXX.com.au/soa" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ing="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXX.Contract.Vault.DataContract" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IService1/DoWork</a:Action>
  <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:b48f6fa8-f5f2-48d8-a06b-1a202c71ed30</a:MessageID>
  <a:ReplyTo>
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
  </a:ReplyTo>
  <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1"></a:To>
  <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
 <u:Created>2015-10-26T10:47:54.721Z</u:Created>
 <u:Expires>2015-10-26T10:53:54.721Z</u:Expires>
  </u:Timestamp>
<Assertion ID="_e058ad04-1d5e-47cf-9fbc-d65aecfaf9ef" IssueInstant="2015-10-24T06:22:37.086Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">...</Assertion>
  </o:Security>
  </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      ....
 .....
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

you see that here the SAML assertion included under  tag, if I remove this then service will not work says security message header not present error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be security tag required since I am using federation binding and Identity model for tokens. anyway java service was able to consume the service after they wrap token in genrericXMLtoken which generates the security tag.